# Ubuntu 14.04 - install color scheme for ssh client terminal

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, colors

I have already set `force_color_prompt=yes` in `~/.bashrc`
Then I connect to ubuntu server 14.04 with ssh, there is still no color.
Why?

And what is the right way to set Ubuntu ssh color scheme via ssh command prompt? 
I tried `.Xresource`and `.Xdefault`, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your .bashrc file is not sourced when you log in via ssh. You can load your .bashrc using the following command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820533/4518341) from Ayman Hourieh for a more permanent fix.

Comment: Regarding the answer you linked, I think the addition should go into ~/.profile, not ~/.bash_profile, since Ubuntu doesn't use .bash_profile by default.

Comment: Oh wait, Ubuntu's default .profile has a section that sources .bashrc... hmm...

Comment: If it helps, I just tried it. I made the addition to the bash_profile of a remote machine. After I ssh'd in the bashrc was loaded. Although i'll admit to having little knowledge about such matters. (Host and remote both running Ubuntu 14.04)